# Joomla changes wont take effect on site

Tags: html, caching, joomla

I am using one template under 1.5 Joomla version and whatever change I do in the CMS backend it wont take effect on site. I checked my browser cache and system cache in Joomla and it still doesnt make a difference.

Any ideas about this ?

Comment: what is not working can you please explain

Comment: Nothing from the backend. When I edit the article, edit the module, change the menu, it's just not showing anything. http://www.villa-ratac.com 

I cleared the cache inside joomla, all that has been there, turned the cache off in configuration file...

Answer (score 0):

If Joomla is anything like Dotnetnuke, then there is a configuration settings on the back end that  manages that.  By default, some appear to quite aggressively cache to save on database hits.  A google search suggests the same and can be seen at http://help.joomla.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=findkey&tmpl=component;1&keyref=screen.cache.15

Otherwise look in the system settings for a "cache" menu or addin.  Hope this helps.

Regards,
Anthony

Comment: Nope. I cleare all the cache that there is. Turned it off, checked the configuration file, deleted it in my browser. Just wont take affect. Could be some bug or server.

Comment: You could also search for the meta tags (pragma-no-cache; pragma-expiry), which you can often add as headers into your page.  it is one or two  lines that essentially forces the browser to not cache.